# Зачем Microsoft в WinApi создает свои макросы для имеющихся в языке определений?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

У меня такой вопрос: зачем `Microsoft` в `WinApi` создает свои макросы для имеющихся в языке определений? Например `CHAR == char`, `DOUBLE == double`, `LPCSTR == char*` и так далее.

Comment: - Скорее всего, из соображений консистентности с принятой схемой нейминга структур — все названия структур в `WinAPI` пишутся заглавными буквами (например, [`LVITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb774760)).

- Соответственно, чтобы сигнатуры функций выглядели консистентно — `DOUBLE MyFunctionName(HANDLE handle, INT something)`, а не `double MyFunctionName(HANDLE handle, int something)`, в какой-то момент было принято решение пере-`typedef`'ить все стандартные типы.

Comment: Это делается не только в Windows API. Почти во всех крупных С/C++ проектах через связку макросов и typedef создают свою систему примитивных типов. Отчасти по соображениям которые привел @Котик, отчасти для того чтобы гарантировать размер/поведение типа данных и тем самым еще больше абстрагировать его от компилятора/архитектуры процессора(ответ @KoVadim). Более того такая техника для целых чисел включена в стандарт и реализована отдельно в заголовочном файле stdint.h.
Вот скажем длинный пример на эту тему из boost
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/cstdint.hpp

Comment: Макросы? Это где это вы увидели у Майкрософта такие макросы? Эти типы у Майкрософта всегда были typedef-именами, а не макросами.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Все очень просто. На самом деле на все стандартные типа накладывается слишком мало ограничений. Тот же `char` по факту может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым. Тот же `double` может иметь различную длину:

> The type double provides at least as much precision as float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as double.

То есть, точная длина в байтах неведома. Да, для конкретной реализации комплятора она известна, но в общем случае — нет.

А теперь представьте себе ситуацию, что есть много-много строк кода, и в один день разработчики компилятора сказали, что `char` у них будет беззнаковый (раньше мне такая ситуация показалась бы  надуманной. Но теперь, когда ARM и MIPS процессоры прочно входят в нашу жизнь, когда 128 битные платформы не за горами, возможно и  не такое). И что теперь делать? Перепроверять тонны кода? Гадать, почему на одной платформе работает, а на другой нет?

Поэтому и определяют свой тип, который имеет **гарантированное поведение**, а также понятное (легко для поиска и восприятия) и не очень длинное (сравните `CHAR` и `signed char`) название.

А вот с типами `LPCSTR` ситуация ещё интереснее. Помню, когда то давно, когда я только начинал изучать си и плюсы, мне нужно было переписать небольшой код, который работал с трехмерными массивами (для кафедры, где я учился). Передача по указателю, когда у тебя три звездочки подряд, запутывает окончательно. Но если объявить тип вида `typedef int*** matrix;`, то передача по ссылке значительно упрощается ( `void func(matrix * data);`) И не нужно думать, сколько там звездочек нужно поставить. От правильно составленной структуры типов продуктивность повышается в разы.

Comment: @KoVadim

     Но теперь, когда arm и mips

А на каких процессорах работал Windows NT 4.0?

Comment: LPCSTR означает, согласно [венгерской нотации](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), применяемой в Microsoft означает Long Pointer to Constant String - то есть длинный указатель на постоянную строку. Длинный указатель в свою очередь анахронизм оставшийся от сегментирования памяти применявшейся в DOS и CP/M

Comment: @alexlz
nt 4.0 работал ещё на aplpha процессорах.

Comment: Википедия: [Количество платформ, для которых существовали релизные версии ОС семейства Windows NT, впечатляет: кроме названных MIPS и Intel x86, сюда входят PowerPC, DEC Alpha, Itanium и AMD x86-64. Независимыми производителями компьютерных систем были также разработаны версии Windows NT для архитектур Clipper (англ.) и SPARC;](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT)

Меня тоже удивило, знал,  что кроме x86 еще MIPS и Alpha

Comment: На самом деле arm, mips и многие другие архитектуры изобрели не вчера. Вероятность того, что винду (условно) потребуется переносить на другую платформу, существует с самого начала (сейчас это не очевидно, но x86 мог и проиграть в гонке платформ).

Comment: @avp Ага. Про PowerPC, Clipper и SPARC не слыхал, ITANIUM'ов и x86-64 ещё не было. А NT 4.0 из коробки был как раз для трёх архитектур.

Comment: >Тот же double может иметь различную длину

@KoVadim извините, возможно я не понял что-то в вашем объяснении, но ведь если double обозвать как DOUBLE он от этого не перестанет быть double'ом? То есть не перестанет в зависимости от реализации иметь различную длину

Comment: Если просто обозвать, то конечно ничего не поменяет. Но ведь никто  не мешает для различных платформ дать различный typedef. И там может скрываться нужный на данной платформе тип.

Answer (score 3):

Это касается почти любой *API*, в том же *OpenGL* и *Direct3D* свои переопределяемые типы. Даже в стандарт *stddef/cstddef* входят переопределяемые типы, такие как *size_t*, *ptrdiff_t* и т.д.

Вот простой пример: ты используешь арифметику указателей на 32-битной платформе в своём проекте, иногда храня указатель в типе *int*, после захочешь перенести свой проект на 64-битную платформу, так вот данный тип *int* для хранения указателя может и не поместится из-за различия размерности *void** (указателя) между *int*. Так вот, тебе придётся везде тип *int* изменить на 64-битный тип, а если бы ты сразу использовал *ptrdiff_t*, то не пришлось бы делать лишнюю работу.

В *WinAPI* есть аналоги типа *INT_PTR/UINT_PTR*, *LONG_PTR/ULONG_PTR*, *DWORD_PTR*...

То же самое касается типов, которые гарантированно дают размерность битности как *UINT8* (1-байт), *UINT16* (2-байта), *UINT32* (4-байта), *UINT64* (8-байт)...

p.s. даже такая истинность — не панацея: `sizeof(int) == sizeof(__int32)` может быть и истинно, а может быть и ложно.