# const vs CONST в чем разница?

Tags: c++, const

Когда писал метод в классе, заметил, что компилятор(VS 2015) распознает const и CONST как разные идентификаторы, почему? Есть ли разница? Для чего переопределили const в CONST?

пример кода:

```
class A{

public:
void a(CONST int& val);//Будет ругаться, что метод не описан!
};

void A::a(const int& val){}
```

Comment: Пример кода не хотите добавить?

Comment: @alexolut - добавил

Comment: Как Вам уже ответили `c++` чувствителен к регистру (это не бейсик). Нельзя писать `CONST` там где нужен `const`. `mAiN`, там где нужен `main` и т.д.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что в исходники часто рассчитаны на компиляцию как в режиме C, так и C++ (например, это так для заголовочных файлов WinAPI).

Для этого можно объявить `CONST` макросом, который раскрывается в `const` при компиляции C++, и в пустую строку при компиляции C.

Это часто используемый в реальности приём.

Выдержка из свежего заголовочного файла WinAPI:

```
#ifndef CONST
#define CONST const
#endif
```

В вашем конкретно случае лучше не заморачиваться, и доопределить `CONST`:

```
#define CONST const
```

(ну или найти какой-нибудь заголовочный файл, в котором он есть).

---

Ещё по теме: [Зачем Microsoft в WinApi создает свои макросы для имеющихся в языке определений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/205348/10105)

Comment: `const` в `c` уже с допотопных времен есть.

Comment: @alexolut Не в MS VC :)

Comment: Какой ревизии VC должен быть? http://rextester.com/EBO9385

Comment: @alexolut: Довольно старый, у меня стоит лишь 2015, так что попробовать не могу. Но Microsoft сохраняет старые определения из-за обратной совместимости.

Comment: Ради прикола установил `MS Developer Studio 97`. Прекрасно работает с `const` в `c` варианте.

Comment: @alexolut: Всё равно разница есть. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6087729/276994. И совместимость WinAPI идёт со времён Windows 2.0.

Comment: А кто говорил, что `const` в `c` такой же как в `c++`? Разговор был о наличии ключевого слова в языке, а не о его поведении.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, для начала `#define CONST const` таки есть в винапишных хедерах, так что вы спорите с фактами.

Comment: Есть. Но мне всё ещё интересно узнать, насколько `Довольно старый` должен быть vc чтобы была необходимость использовать `CONST`, а не `const`. Если я Вас правильно понял, Вам всё же доводилось использовать такой компилятор. Значит, надо просто вспомнить :)

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то C++ чувствителен к регистру, так что `const` - ключевое слово, а `CONST` - так, обычный идентификатор...

```
const int CONST = 1;
```

вполне компилируется :)

Comment: существует также еще очень маленькая вероятность того, что у него где-то в коде имеется что-то в духе `#define CONST const` :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive У него - вполне, а в Visual C++ 2015 - такого точно нет...

Comment: @VladD вот считает иначе.

Comment: @alexolut Еще раз - да, такое переопределение есть в Windows Kit, но в самом компиляторе и его заголовочных файлах такого нет. В исходной постановке вопроса не было речи о том, что клиент подключает `<windows.h>` или что еще. Был вопрос о чистом VC++ 2015 - *компилятор(VS 2015) распознает const и CONST как разные идентификаторы*. Т.е. вообще подразумевалось, что он НЕ ДОЛЖЕН их различать - что уж совсем ерунда. Я ответил на то, что было написано :)

Comment: Всё повязано друг с другом, [например](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk): `If you uninstall components that other apps use, you’ll run into problems. For example, Visual Studio also uses the Windows SDK.`. Ну, да ладно. У меня пока осталась неясность - в какой же версии vc `const` не работал в `c`, что об этом всё ещё актуально думать в контексте современной разработки.

Comment: @alexolut Насколько я помню - но не уверен - можно было ставить VC++ и без Windows SDK. В свое время Express какой-то точно так и шел. Что до версии - то все, что могу сказать я - что в 2010 `const` уже точно работал.

Comment: Да и в `97` работал :) Надо что-то типа `Microsoft C 1.0` проверить.